# how to join multiple tables without showing repeated data?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I pop into a problem recently, and Im sure its because of how I Join them.
this is my code:

```
select LP_Pending_Info.Service_Order,
    LP_Pending_Info.Pending_Days,
    LP_Pending_Info.Service_Type,
    LP_Pending_Info.ASC_Code,
    LP_Pending_Info.Model,
    LP_Pending_Info.IN_OUT_WTY, 
    LP_Part_Codes.PartCode,
    LP_PS_Codes.PS,
    LP_Confirmation_Codes.SO_NO,
    LP_Pending_Info.Engineer_Code
from LP_Pending_Info

join LP_Part_Codes 
on LP_Pending_Info.Service_order = LP_Part_Codes.Service_order

join LP_PS_Codes 
on LP_Pending_Info.Service_Order = LP_PS_Codes.Service_Order

join LP_Confirmation_Codes 
on LP_Pending_Info.Service_Order = LP_Confirmation_Codes.Service_Order

order by LP_Pending_Info.Service_order, LP_Part_Codes.PartCode;
```

[image]

For every service order I have 5 part code maximum.

### If the service order have only one value it show the result correctly but when it have more than one Part code the problem begin.

for example: this service order"4182134076" has only 2 part code, first'GH81-13601A' and second 'GH96-09938A' so it should show the data 2 time but it repeat it for 8 time. what seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your records were exactly the same the `distinct` keyword would have solved it.

However in rows 2 and 3 which have the same `Service_Order` and `Part_Code` if you check the `SO_NO` you see it is different - that is why distinct won't work here - the rows are not identical.

I say you have some problem in one of the conditions in your `join`s. The different data is in the `SO_NO` column so check the raw data in the `LP_Confirmation_Codes` table for that `Service_Order`:

```
select * from LP_Confirmation_Codes where Service_Order = 4182134076
```

I assume you are missing an `and` with the value from the `LP_Part_Codes` or  `LP_PS_Codes` (but can't be sure without seeing those tables and data myself).

By this sentence *If the service order have only one value it show the result correctly but when it have more than one Part code the problem begin.* - probably you are missing and `and` with the `LP_Part_Codes` table

Comment: part code,PS and SO are each in a different table but I use the service order as the primary key in the table, I've tried all of the Joins  but nothing helped.

Comment: What are the columns of the `LP_Part_Codes` and `LP_PS_Codes`?

Comment: when I used your select code it returns this:                           4182134076 1.00024e+009
4182134076 1.00022e+009 and its correct cause I have 2 part Code so I need 2 SO as well.

Comment: @alijavadi - ya - that is what I assumed and that is why I'm asking the columns you have - you are missing an `and` in that last join` so for each row you find 2 matches in the `LP_Confirmation_Codes` where you were supposed to actually find only 1

Comment: when I use one of the joins the data is correct but when I use the other ones it show me wrong data.

Comment: Please show how rows look in the other tables for that `Service_Order` so I can see what conditions you are missing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118497/discussion-between-gilad-green-and-ali-javadi).

Comment: when I put the 'and' in the last join it return error?!? but when I have 2 part code I need two SO number as well, why you saying I need one SO for two part code when each of them should have a different SO_NO?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your output result, here are the following data that caused multiple output.

`Service Order: 4182134076` has :

2 `PartCode` which are `GH81-13601A` and `GH96-09938A`

2 `PS` which are `U` and `P`

2 `SO_NO` which are `1.00024e+09` and `1.00022e+09`

Therefore 2^3 returns 8 rows. I believe that you need to check where you should join your tables.

Answer (score -1):

Use [DINTINCT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

```
select distinct LP_Pending_Info.Service_Order,LP_Pending_Info.Pending_Days,
LP_Pending_Info.Service_Type,LP_Pending_Info.ASC_Code,LP_Pending_Info.Model,
LP_Pending_Info.IN_OUT_WTY, LP_Part_Codes.PartCode,LP_PS_Codes.PS,
LP_Confirmation_Codes.SO_NO,LP_Pending_Info.Engineer_Code
from LP_Pending_Info
 join LP_Part_Codes on LP_Pending_Info.Service_order = LP_Part_Codes.Service_order
 join LP_PS_Codes on LP_Part_Codes.Service_Order = LP_PS_Codes.Service_Order
 join LP_Confirmation_Codes on LP_PS_Codes.Service_Order = LP_Confirmation_Codes.Service_Order
order by LP_Pending_Info.Service_order, LP_Part_Codes.PartCode;
```

distinct will not return duplicates based on your select. So if a row is same, it will only return once.

Comment: Unfortunately this will not help in his case